# __unicode__ function works locally but not on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, unicode

I have done a simple app with an admin interface that works great locally.

I have deployed it on heroku successfully.

this is my models.py

```
class Club(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, verbose_name=_("name"))

    def __unicode__(self):
         return self.name

class Party(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, verbose_name=_("name"))
       club = models.ForeignKey(Club, verbose_name=_('club'))

       def __unicode__(self):
           return self.name
```

**Locally,** in the admin interface, in the `Parties` table, I can see `Club's name` under the club column, which is the result of the `__unicode__`

But, In **heroku**, the `__unicode__` method doesn't work, I get `ClubObject` in the party's club column instead.

I'm using python 2.7.

Any help?

Comment: Are you *sure* you're using Python 2.7 on Heroku? Sounds like you are actually using Python 3.

Comment: you are right, I corrected it by adding a `runtime.txt` that contains `python-2.7.12`, Thanks :D

Comment: You might want to consider the alternative (making your code compatible with Python 3) as well.